# How to know how many tabs are open via selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

When I navigate through my site via Selenium, I clicks on some links.
I want to check if it was opened in new tab or not.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(options).build();

driver.get('https://sidanmor.com').then();

driver.sleep(5000);    

// click some links

// Here I need code that checks the number of tabs

driver.quit();
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Here you go... I have added my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getAllWindowHandles method:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(options).build();

driver.get('https://sidanmor.com').then();

driver.sleep(5000);    

// click some links

driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (windowHandles) {
    console.log('Number of tabs = ' + windowHandles.length);
});

driver.quit();
```